# Rails 4 ActiveRecord - how to work with data if the query is made as ".find_by_sql"?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

It's a bit beniger-like question, but I need to make a query like this:

```
@data = Car.find_by_sql("SELECT cars.*, colors.*, customers.*....
```

And I struggling with how t access those data. I tried to iterate through cars this way:

```
@data[:card].each do |car|
 ...
```

and I found there the cars.

But when I try the same approach for `colors` and `customers`, there's nothing - specifically:
    @data[:colors].each do |color|
     ...

there's nothing... What's the right way to iterate through other models' data?

Thank you guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you query data like this `Car.find_by_sql` then all returned fields will act like they were attributes on an instance of a `Car`.

If in your example the cars table had a `brand` field, the colors table a `color` column and a customer had a `name`, then the returned instances of a `Car` would respond to all those methods with the corresponding values:

```
@date.each do |sold_car|
  sold_car.brand           # from cars table
  sold_car.color           # from color table
  sold_car.name            # from customers table
end
```

Comment: Thank you @spickermann for your answer. What if I would need to work in the loop with columns that have the same name for each model? Typically `id`s (`cars.id`, `colours.id`, `customers.id`). How to access these?

Comment: And question 2 – as I have all the data (from different models) in the `@data` variable, is there any way to loop only through `customers` (through a single model)? For example, I'd like to know how many `customers` the query fetched, how many `cars` etc.

Comment: @user2932090:  You have to rename the columns in SQL (`customers.id AS customer_id`) if multiple columns have the same name. I cannot answer you seconds question, because I do not know why you use `find_by_sql` and how your query looks. But there is certainly a Rails way to do that.

Comment: thank you. I am going to dig into it. I don't like `find_by_sql` either, but in this case the query is very big and using ActiveRecord tools doesn't help to get the desired results from the needed database tables.